# web Разрешение и размер экрана

Tags: html, веб-программирование, вёрстка, viewport

Ко мне попал дизайн мобильного web приложения, который выполнен в разрешении айфона (width: 1080px;
height: 1920px;) и все размеры отступов и шрифтов указаны в соответствии с этим разрешением.

Но я работаю в контексте web размером (ширина того же айфона: 375px), как настроить это соответствие?

Я понимаю, что тут что-то нужно сделать с тегом viewport, но как не ковыряюсь с ним, ничего не выходит, весь инет облазил.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, просто уменьшить все размеры в 2.88 раз?

Comment: Вообще, что значит "попал дизайн"? Речь о макете, о готовой вёрстке или о чём-то другом?

Comment: Речь о макете в фигме. Я понимаю, что никто меня не заставляет использовать заданные там значения в точности, но использовать не их будет гораздо сложнее

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, разобравшись с вьюпортом:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3472222222222222, user-scalable=No" />
```